# Unable to get UIPanGesturerRecognizer to work for child UIView of parent UIImageView - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an application that has a UIImageView that has a subview(UIView) that contains CAShapeLayer which i used to draw a blue circle.  I would like the user to be able to drag the blue circle anywhere over the UIImageView.  My problem is the following.  I have made the CAShapeLayer to be the same CGRect as the parent UIView so that the user has to actually touch the blue circle before be able to drag it around.  When I do this, my translations no longer work.  However, if i make the the UIView frame the same as the parent UIImagView, the dragging of the blue circle is enabled, but then the user does not necessarily have to be touch the blue circle to be able to drag it around.

```
class DrawCircleViewController: UIViewController {

var circleSize = CGRect.init(x: 60, y: 80, width: 15, height: 15)
var firstDotView: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!


// LAYERS
let layer1 = CAShapeLayer()
let layer2 = CAShapeLayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstDotView = UIView.init()
    firstDotView?.frame = circleSize

    imgView.addSubview(firstDotView!)

    // DRAW A FILLED IN BLUE CIRCLE
    drawBlueCircle()

    imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    firstDotView!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // ADD GESTURE RECOGNIZER
    let firstDotPanRecgnzr = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(firstDotHandler(sender:)))
    firstDotView?.addGestureRecognizer(firstDotPanRecgnzr)

}


@objc func firstDotHandler(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {

    let firstDot = sender.view
    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
    if(sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed){
        firstDot?.center = CGPoint.init(x: (firstDot?.center.x)! + translation.x, y: (firstDot?.center.y)! + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}



func drawBlueCircle(){

    layer1.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: circleSize, cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    layer1.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    firstDotView?.layer.addSublayer(layer1)
}

}
```

[sceen shot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFBIz.jpg)

Comment: I think you need to make your view that contains dot slightly bigger than the dot, so it has more space for interaction. Just move this view around. Or am I getting your problem wrong?

Comment: you are correct in understanding my probelm

Comment: For the sake of simplicity in debugging this, add some background color to your parentView that contains your dot. Now the problem might be with your translation code. instead of `sender.tranlsaltion(in: view)` try `sender.translation(in: imgView)`